# Flutter - popup menu isn't closed after selecting an item

Tags: flutter

I am experimenting with Flutter and having a problem with `PopupMenuButton`. After selecting an item in the menu I show a new screen without the menu, and after I navigate back the popup menu is still open - as shown in the following screenshots:

[image: Popup menu]
[image: Edit profile]

After navigating back from the edit profile screen (2nd screenshot) to the account screen (1st screenshot) the pop up menu is still open. I would like it to be closed. The relevant code where I create the popup menu inside an appbar:

```
      actions: <Widget>[
    new PopupMenuButton(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return <PopupMenuEntry>[
          new AppBarMenuItem("Edit profile", () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.editProfile)).build(context),
          new AppBarMenuItem("Option 1", () => {}).build(context),
          new AppBarMenuItem("Option 2", () => {}).build(context),
          new AppBarMenuItem("Option 3", () => {}).build(context),
          new AppBarMenuItem("Option 4", () => {}).build(context),
        ];
      },
    ),
  ],
```

And the `AppBarMenuItem`:

```
new PopupMenuItem(
  child: new InkWell(
    child: new Text(_label),
    onTap: _onTap,
)
```

How can I make sure that the popup menu gets closed after selecting an item? It looks like if I just use `PopupMenuItem` in my `PopupMenuButton` and navigate to the new screen in the `onSelected` function the menu closes properly. But when I use the `onTap` function of `InkWell` it doesn't close anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as stated in the documentation the popup menu should automatically close when user selects an option from the popup menu item. 
Using `InkWell` onTap wont automatically close the popup menu rather directly use the popup menu item to automatically close the popup menu when an item is selected from the popupMenuList
Make sure that the `value` property of the `PopupMenuItem` is not null otherwise the `onSelected` function will not be called when the `PopupMenuItem` is selected

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work. The popup menu is still open after navigating back.

Comment: `const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: 'Hooray!',
                child: const Text('Hooray!')
              ),`  take this popup menu item just to test and add it to your popup menu. Select this from popup menu and see if the menu closes if it does that means there is an issue that popup menu wont close if you call the navigator.pushNamed immediately after selecting a popup menu item. don't use you custom popup menu item here just a regular one .

Comment: I have `InkWell` as child of `PopupMenuItem`, and I use its `onTap` to navigate to another screen. It looks like there is indeed an issue with this, because it works when I use a plain `PopupMenuItem` and navigate within the `onSelected` function. That looks like a bug to me, I would expect it to be closed in the first case as well.

Comment: You said in your question that you were returning a modified `PopupMenuItem` from `AppBarMenuItem` so i didn't ask for its code but i think you should update the question so if anyone comes here it might help him too. you were using `InkWell` instead of simple popup menu item that's y it wasn't working in your case.

Comment: if we take a list tile for example and put a trailing icon button on it . then we press the icon button , only icon button onTap works not the `ListTile` onTap . so in your case the popup menu item isnt selected as far as complier is concerned for the compiler you are selecting the `InkWell` and not the `PopupMenuItem`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I ended up just using `PopupMenuItem` and the `onSelected` function. Another important thing to note is a `value` must be given to `PopupMenuItem`, otherwise `onSelected` isn't even called when that item is selected. Please edit your answer to mention these points and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Could you remove the `Navigator.pop(context)` part? It's not relevant to the problem. Actual problem is using the `onTap` function of `InkWell`, which should be mentioned in the answer. I tried editing your answer, but some SO member rejected it for some reason, obviously without understanding the problem and the answer here.

Comment: i hope this soln is fine .

Answer (score 25):

Just use `pop` inside your `onTap` function `Navigator.pop(context, "$popupValue");`

```
PopupMenuItem<String>(
    value: "Replay Game",
    child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.replay,
            color: theme.actionButtonColor),
        title: Text("Replay Game"),
        onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, "Replay Game");
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text("Clear input and replay game?"),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                child: Text("No"),
                                textColor: theme.alterDialogActionColor,
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                    store.dispatch(ReplayAction(timerBloc, varBloc.fireAnalytics));
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: Text("Yes"),
                                textColor: theme.alterDialogActionColor,
                            ),
                        ],
                    );
                });
        },
    ),
)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. What was your process to figure out that this was what you needed to do?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and here is my solution.  Your `PopUpMenuButton()` is not utilizing the `onSelected` property.  The `onSelected` property will properly close your `PopUpMenuButton`.  It currently is not because the `onTap` property of your `AppBarMenuItem` is taking over that job.
Also, I created a list of `PopUpMenuItem`, instead of `PopUpMenuEntry`, not sure if that makes a difference.  But for each of my `PopUpMenuItem`, I also assigned the value property to each, so that the `onSelected` would communicate to the `PopUpMenuButton()` which item was tapped.

Something like this:

```
PopupMenuButton(
                onSelected: (selection) {
                  switch (selection) {
                    case 1:
                      ... do stuff...
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      ... break stuff...
                      );
                      break;
                  }
                },
```

Where case 1, case 2, etc refer to the value property I assigned to the `PopUpMenuItem()`.

Comment: Please take a look at this edit and learn our code formatting.

Comment: I was wondering how to properly utilize PopupMenuButton as intended. I was previously adding ListTile as a child, and calling navigation onTap. This onSelected method seems more intended.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a onTap property, Use Navigator.pop(context) which first closes the popup menu then Navigate to the desired screen.

```
Inkwell( 
  onTap: (){
       Navigator.pop(context);
     }
 )
```